# Having trouble while installing magento using XAMPP server

Tags: php, magento, xampp

I am using XAMPP server and want to install magento framework. However while installing after filling up the configuration page and clicking continue the page is reloading and a blank page is coming. Tell me how to fix this?

Comment: you better visit: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have not set the pre-configuration settings correctly. Try with a clean install following any of these tutorials: [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_on_windows_with_xampp_and_wamp), or [this](http://tutorialmagento.com/how-to-install-magento-on-xampp-localhost) (second one is easier and more descriptive) and make sure you have done all pre-configurations correctly. Furthermore never forget to check the logs. Most of the times for blank pages there are pretty good answers in log files ;)